# PHP Mail content doesn't display in Outlook

Tags: php, html, css, email, outlook

So I've been messing around a little bit, and continued to inprove my PHP mails. Everything worked good, had my up and downs, and I finally achieved what I wanted to.

This is what it looked like

```
<?php 

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8>\n";
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_age = $_POST['Alter'];
$field_ges = $_POST['Geschlecht'];
$field_gt = $_POST['Gamertag'];
$field_sona = $_POST['Socname'];
$field_rol = $_POST['Rolle'];
$overall_message = 'Vorname: ' . $field_name . '<br>
Alter: ' . $field_age . '<br>
Geschlecht: ' . $field_ges . '<br>
Gamertag: ' . $field_gt . '<br>
SocialClub-Name: ' . $field_sona . '<br>
Rolle: ' . $field_rol;

$subject = 'xRL Anmeldung - ' . $field_rol . ': ' . $field_name;
$body_message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#Mailnap {
    text-align: center;
}

#Mailna {
    text-align: center;
}

.Hgrund {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

table {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}

.Header {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    border: 0px;
}

.Header th {
    width: 83px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.Header td {
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Header td a {
    fonz-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Header td a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FF0000;
}

.Content {
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #696969;
    margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
    padding: 0;
}

.ContentICBG {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.Content h1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D5C4A1;
    color: #000000;
}

.ContentICBG p {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="Mailnap"><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/DE/MailFeedback" id="Mailna">Wird diese Mail nicht richtig angezeigt? Klicke bitte hier, und lasse es und wissen!</a></p>

<div class="Hgrund">
<table style="background-color:#DCDCDC;border-bottom:3px solid #DCDCDC;">
 <tr class="Header">
  <th><img src="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/Clans/GTAxRL/xRLN60.png"/></th>
  <td><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/DE/" style="">STARTSEITE</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/DE/Gaming-News/" style="">GAMING NEWS</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/Forum" style="">Forum</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/Clans/SEK1" style="">SEK1</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/Clans/GTAxRL/" style="">xRL</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div class="Content">
 <h1>' . $subject . '</h1>
 <div class="ContentICBG">
  <p>' . $overall_message . '</p>
 </div>
  <h1>Gesendet von: ' . $field_name . '</h1>
</div>

<div style="margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#1F1F1F;border-top:3px solid #DCDCDC;height:30px;width:100%">
 <p style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:right;font-size:15px;margin:10px 10px 0 0;padding:0;"><a style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;" href="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/About">Über</a> | &copy;2017 xForigens</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'; 

$mail_to = 'Admin@xForigens.com';
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Danke, wir werden uns in den nächsten 7 Tagen melden.\n\nDamit Du mit am Projekt teilnehmen kannst, musst Du nun mit deinem angegebenen Gamertag, und deinem SocialClub-Name anfragen an Crew & Club senden!')
  window.history.back()
  </script>
<?php
}

else { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Wenn die Mailfunktion ausfällt, versuche diese erneut zu senden, oder wende Dich an die Administration.')
  window.history.back();
  </script>
<?php
}

?>
```

Everything was great. So I added a few more lines, because I would like my own Adress to be displayed, etc., and not cgi-mailer@kundenserver.de.

Now it looked like this

```
<?php 

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8>\n";
$headers .= "From: xForigens | xRL<NoReply@xForigens.com>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: MailFeedback<Admin@xForigens.com>\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\n";
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_age = $_POST['Alter'];
$field_ges = $_POST['Geschlecht'];
$field_gt = $_POST['Gamertag'];
$field_sona = $_POST['Socname'];
$field_rol = $_POST['Rolle'];
$overall_message = 'Vorname: ' . $field_name . '<br>
Alter: ' . $field_age . '<br>
Geschlecht: ' . $field_ges . '<br>
Gamertag: ' . $field_gt . '<br>
SocialClub-Name: ' . $field_sona . '<br>
Rolle: ' . $field_rol;

$subject = 'xRL Anmeldung - ' . $field_rol . ': ' . $field_name;
$body_message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#Mailnap {
    text-align: center;
}

#Mailna {
    text-align: center;
}

.Hgrund {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

table {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}

.Header {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    border: 0px;
}

.Header th {
    width: 83px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.Header td {
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Header td a {
    fonz-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Header td a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FF0000;
}

.Content {
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #696969;
    margin: 0 1% 0 1%;
    padding: 0;
}

.ContentICBG {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.Content h1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D5C4A1;
    color: #000000;
}

.ContentICBG p {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="Mailnap"><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/DE/MailFeedback" id="Mailna">Wird diese Mail nicht richtig angezeigt? Klicke bitte hier, und lasse es und wissen!</a></p>

<div class="Hgrund">
<table style="background-color:#DCDCDC;border-bottom:3px solid #DCDCDC;">
 <tr class="Header">
  <th><img src="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/Clans/GTAxRL/xRLN60.png"/></th>
  <td><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/DE/" style="">STARTSEITE</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/DE/Gaming-News/" style="">GAMING NEWS</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xGamesHub.com/Forum" style="">Forum</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/Clans/SEK1" style="">SEK1</a></td>
  <td><a href="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/Clans/GTAxRL/" style="">xRL</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div class="Content">
 <h1>' . $subject . '</h1>
 <div class="ContentICBG">
  <p>' . $overall_message . '</p>
 </div>
  <h1>Gesendet von: ' . $field_name . '</h1>
</div>

<div style="margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#1F1F1F;border-top:3px solid #DCDCDC;height:30px;width:100%">
 <p style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:right;font-size:15px;margin:10px 10px 0 0;padding:0;"><a style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;" href="https://xForigens.com/de-DE/About">Über</a> | &copy;2017 xForigens</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'; 

$mail_to = 'Admin@xForigens.com';
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Danke, wir werden uns in den nächsten 7 Tagen melden.\n\nDamit Du mit am Projekt teilnehmen kannst, musst Du nun mit deinem angegebenen Gamertag, und deinem SocialClub-Name anfragen an Crew & Club senden!')
  window.history.back()
  </script>
<?php
}

else { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Wenn die Mailfunktion ausfällt, versuche diese erneut zu senden, oder wende Dich an die Administration.')
  window.history.back();
  </script>
<?php
}

?>
```

In Outlook.com it doesn't display any content anymore, accents (or whatever those were again) like ÄÖÜ/äöü don't properly display anymore, and different mailservices now ask me if I would like my header picture to be displayed. Before it did without beeing asked. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your first header is:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8>\n";
```

Ignoring the rogue > you have in there, you are specifying UTF-8.

UTF-8 has no support for umlauts etc, you need to encode all the special characters.

Comment: I didn't notice the ">" lol. After deleting that, umlaute, such as the footers link "Über" are now displaying correctly again. I didn't think that I would have support for umlaute as well, but I've been told different. And after deleting the >, it's working as it should.

Thanks